# Invalid Enumerant

Tags: python, opengl, graphics

I am using OpenGL to draw a line. The code is:

```
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *
from OpenGL.GLUT import *
import sys
def init():
    glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
    gluOrtho2D(-100.0, 100.0, -100.0, 100.0)

def plotpoints():
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
    glColor3f(0.0, 0.5, 0.0)
    glPointSize(4.0)
    glBegin(GL_LINE)
    glVertex2f(50.0,0.0)
    glVertex2f(10.0,0.0)
    glEnd()
    glFlush()

def main():
    glutInit(sys.argv)
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE|GLUT_RGB)
    glutInitWindowSize(500,500)
    glutInitWindowPosition(100,100)
    glutCreateWindow("Again")
    glutDisplayFunc(plotpoints)
    init()
    glutMainLoop()

main()
```

The problem is, on execution I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\OpenGL\GLUT\special.py", line 121, in safeCall
    return function( *args, **named )
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\eclipse\Python Projects\Serverclient\Try.py", line 16, in plotpoints
    glEnd()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\OpenGL\latebind.py", line 61, in __call__
    return self.wrapperFunction( self.baseFunction, *args, **named )
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\OpenGL\GL\exceptional.py", line 57, in glEnd
    return baseFunction( )
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\OpenGL\error.py", line 208, in glCheckError
    baseOperation = baseOperation,
GLError: GLError(
    err = 1280,
    description = 'invalid enumerant',
    baseOperation = glEnd,
    cArguments = ()
)
GLUT Display callback <function plotpoints at 0x02D6FAB0> with (),{} failed: returning None GLError(
    err = 1280,
    description = 'invalid enumerant',
    baseOperation = glEnd,
    cArguments = ()
)
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that you need `GL_LINES` in the call to `glBegin()` rather than `GL_LINE`. They are 2 different values used for 2 different things.

Comment: Can you please tell me whats the difference? As in what are they used for? And Invalid Entrant was because of the wrong keyword specified in glBegin()?

Comment: If you look in the header for OpenGL, you'll find all the enumerated values that you can pass to various gl functions. `GL_LINES` is defined to be 1, and `GL_LINE` is defined to be 0x1B01. `GL_LINES` is used for immediate mode drawing of a series of lines as you intended above, whereas `GL_LINE` is used for setting the polygon mode (which can be point, line, or fill). See [`glPolygonMode()`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man4/html/glPolygonMode.xhtml) for more information on that.